# Understanding a passage written about an exponential function

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, calculus

I read the following in the book *[Forecasting, Time Series, and Regression - Fourth Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534409776)* by Bowerman - O'Connell - Koehler (P. 296), and it said the following:

> It can be shown that as the power $λ$ approaches zero, the transformed value $y^λ$ approaches $\ln y$, the natural logarithm of $y$...

To the best of my knowledge, when a number is raised to the zero power, it equals $1$, and also the limit equals $1$. Is there any way to explain this passage in the book, or is this an error?

Comment: I don't have the book. Were they discussing the [Box-Cox family of transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box.E2.80.93Cox_transformation)?

Comment: @gung. No they were not. The transformation in the book does not depend on lambda.

Comment: Can you add some context? What were they talking about?

Comment: It's a limit. Use L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is not actually quite right; as $\lambda\to 0$, $y^\lambda$ doesn't approach $\ln y$.

As you said, $\lim_{\lambda\to 0} y^\lambda$ is $1$, irrespective of the value of $y$ (as long as it's positive).

However, a linear transformation of $y^\lambda$ *does* approach $\ln y$.

If we let

$$t(\lambda) = \frac{y^\lambda-1}{\lambda}$$

-- a transformation familiar to many because of the Box-Cox family of transformations, then

$$\lim_{\lambda\to 0} t(\lambda) = \ln y\,.$$

Note that both the numerator and the denominator go to $0$; we can make use of L'Hopital's rule. Also recall that $\frac{d}{dx} a^x = a^x \ln a$.

So

$$\lim_{\lambda\to 0} t(\lambda) = \frac{\lim_{\lambda\to 0} \frac{d}{d\lambda}(y^\lambda-1)}{\lim_{\lambda\to 0}\frac{d}{d\lambda}\lambda}$$

Which you should have no trouble showing to be $\ln y$.

(Another approach might be to write $y^\lambda$ in the numerator as $\exp(\lambda \ln y)$ and then expand the $\exp$ function as a series, before cancelling down and taking limits.)